# Все остальные вопросы(,) если не разрешатся сами собой, то хотя бы утратят былую насущность. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

**Когда же он задумается над этим одним, все остальные вопросы если не разрешатся сами собой, то хотя бы утратят былую насущность.**

Если – это часть составного союза, просто здесь такой интересный порядок союзов и главной и подчинительной части? Нужна тогда, получается, запятая?

**(Когда же он задумается над этим одним), [все остальные вопросы, (если не разрешатся сами собой), то хотя бы утратят былую насущность].** => **(Когда же он задумается над этим одним), [все остальные вопросы то хотя бы утратят былую насущность].** Выбрасываем подчинительную часть с если – получается что-то странное: "то" не вписывается. С другой стороны, если поставить "то" перед  *все остальные вопросы...*, мы просто восстановим составной союз когда...то:(**Когда** же он задумается над этим одним), **то** [все остальные вопросы, (***если*** не разрешатся сами собой), ***то*** хотя бы утратят былую насущность]. Но второе "то" в составном союзе "если...то" должно тоже относится к *все остальные вопросы*... Может, не надо запятой?

- Помогите понять это предложение.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна. Союз **если не...  то** соединяет однородные члены предложения.

Ср.: Туманы в Лондоне бывают **если не** каждый день, **то** через день непременно (Гонч.);

В это лето дожди шли **если не** каждый день, **то** через день или два и отличались каким-то назойливым постоянством.

[См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. / Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112)

[Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=102#pp102)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А как понять эти примеры (Розенталь): Тёплая погода если и вернётся, то не надолго (простое предложение, запятая перед если не ставится). Здесь нет однородных членов предложения, которые бы соединял составной союз если не...то. И там же: Тёплая погода, если она и вернётся, то не надолго (сложное предложение, запятая ставится). Здесь "если и... то не" тоже однородные члены соединяет?